# How can I modify api response

Tags: javascript, arrays

From api response I got an array which I shared at below but in my select component I always use Id and Name so how can change the response with new response and set it into the select.

```
0:
Id: "737ded71-e6b7-4f54-b0fd-2e757ae3d152"
UserType: 0
RoleType: 8
RoleName: "ABC"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)

// How I want it to be is;
0:
Code: "737ded71-e6b7-4f54-b0fd-2e757ae3d152"
UserType: 0
Id: 8
Name: "ABC"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: which Id field should be correct in your example: Id: 8 or Id: "737ded71-e6b7-4f54-b0fd-2e757ae3d152" ??

Comment: I need only RoleType  which will be Id and RoleName which will be Name then I can use in select like that bcuz 
 {items.map(item => (
                    <MenuItem key={item.Id} value={item.Id}>
                        {item.Name}
                    </MenuItem>
                ))}
I use my select component like that

Comment: So the other Id can be removed?

Comment: 0:
Id: "737ded71-e6b7-4f54-b0fd-2e757ae3d152"
UserType: 0
Code: 8
Name: "ABC"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)

let it be Code not Id then how can I edit like that

Comment: @ŞehirRehberi This question is more likely to be reopened if you update it with the information you have added in your comments.

Answer (score 1):

the better way to do it is use *map* function:

```
const data = response.map(item => ({ Id: item.RoleType, Name: item.RoleName }));
```